# E/WindowManager: Activity has leaked window that was originally added here

Tags: android, memory-leaks, progressdialog

I am getting [image: This] Error

So below is my code,

```
public class SendMail extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {

private Context context;
private Session session;
private String email;
private String subject;
private String message;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

public SendMail(Context context,String email, String subject,String message){

    this.context = context;
    this.email = email;
    this.subject = subject;
    this.message = message;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {

    super.onPreExecute();
    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context,"Sending Email","Please Wait...",false,false);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {

    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    progressDialog.dismiss();
    Toast.makeText(context,"Email Sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

    Properties props = new Properties();

    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port","465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth","true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port","465");

    session =Session.getDefaultInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator(){
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication(){
            return new
                    PasswordAuthentication(Config.EMAIL, Config.PASSWORD);
        }
    });
    try {

        MimeMessage mm = new MimeMessage(session);
        mm.setFrom(new InternetAddress(Config.EMAIL));
        mm.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(email));
        mm.setSubject(subject);
        mm.setText(message);
        Transport.send(mm);

    }catch (MessagingException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
 }
```

I know I get an error because ProgressDialog is running while my Activity is destroyed.I should put a progressDialog.dismiss().so i put it but still, I'm getting this error.

I don't know how to solve this issue.Hope someone to help me.

Comment: put progressDialog.dismiss() in ondestroy method of activity

Comment: its because your activity or `fragment` is crashing or not stopping properly , and `progressDialog` is not `dismissed` so you are getting `leaked window` error

Comment: I already have dismissed my progressDialog in onPostExecute

Comment: @shivanipatil that's what I was saying your activity or whatever is crashing ,meaning either your code is crashing before `onPosteExecute` called

Comment: so what exactly I have to do.I don't know how to solve this issue

Comment: How are you calling _SendMail_ in your activity ?

Comment: Creating SendMail object like this, `SendMail sm = new SendMail(this, email, subject, message);` and Executing sendemail to send email `sm.execute();`